# Androidruntime: FATAL EXCEPTION's

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I have coded my project in AndroidStudio version 1.5 and after some time I  coded the same project for version 2.1.2 (mostly copy pasted my java methods from old project) and now its showing me FATAL EXCEPTION 16 errors what I should do to get rid of these errors.
Following are the exceptions.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imtiaz.recognizer/com.example.imtiaz.recognizer.MainActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2232)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:116)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `at com.example.imtiaz.recognizer.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)` What is line 26 of `MainActivity.java`? Also post the rest of the constructor.

Comment: You might have call findViewById() for your field or fields before OnCreate(). Use them in OnCreate().

Comment: Yeah I have initialized accidently only one field in subclass of Activity. rebuilding the project and I will Update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
at com.example.imtiaz.recognizer.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
...
```

It appears that you call `findViewById()` in the constructor of your `Activity` subclass. You cannot do this. You must do all initialization in the `onCreate()` method instead. I strongly suggest you learn about the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). You must use this correctly in order to write any Android apps.

Comment: I did not call findViewById() in subclass of my Activity.

Comment: @ABi The stack trace you posted says otherwise. Please edit your question with the code for the constructor of `MainActivity` and indicate where line 26 is.

Comment: My appologies yes I have used findViewById() for one field.

Comment: @ABi That is not allowed because none of the views have been created when your constructor is called. See the link I gave about the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, my app is running but stops on 2nd activity when click on event/delegate, I think its because of progress-bar may be. I will update my code in morning.

Comment: @ABi Please post the new problem as a new question.

Comment: yeah sure, 1st thing at morning.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that bug you have to mention all the `activity` components inside the `onCreate` method itself and also within the class as I shown below

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView ForgetPass;
private Button Login,Signup;
private EditText UserName,Password;


onCreate 
{
    Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    Signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    ForgetPass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgetPass);
    UserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
}
```